# How to use linqtotwitter V3

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

Alright I recently upgraded to V3 but it broken many things

How can I fix these ?

Number 1 :

This is not working anymore no such definition as Credentials and InMemoryCredentials

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
    {
        ConsumerKey = srtwitterConsumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = srtwitterConsumerSecret,
        OAuthToken = srtwitterOAuthToken,
        AccessToken = srtwitterAccessToken
        }
};
```

Number 2 : no definition for GetFileBytes anymore

```
var mediaItems =
new List<Media>
{
    new Media
    {                 
        Data = Utilities.GetFileBytes(srImageUrl),
        FileName = srTweet.Split(' ')[0]+".jpg",
        ContentType = MediaContentType.Jpeg
    }
};
```

Number 3 : no definition for TweetWithMedia

```
var tweet = twitterContext.TweetWithMedia(srTweet, false, mediaItems);
```

Number 4 : no definition for UpdateStatus

```
var tweet = twitterContext.UpdateStatus(srTweet);
```

Number 5 : no definition for CreateFavorite

```
var vrResult = twitterContext.CreateFavorite(srRetweetId);
```

And i can not find any example for V3

It always say `twitterCtx` but how do you get `twitterCtx` in the first place ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LINQ to Twitter v3.0 is async, which means that naming conventions have changed as well as the way to call some code. Some changes were for consistency or improving cross-platform operation. It's also a Portable Class Library (PCL), which allows it to run on multiple platforms. Here's a quick rundown on some of your questions:

1. Try this:

   ```
       var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
       {
           CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
           {
               ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"],
               ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"],
               AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessToken"],
               AccessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessTokenSecret"]
           }
       };
   ```
2. The previous implementation of GetFileBytes has cross-platform issues, so I removed it. You'll have to write your own code to read the bytes of the file. Here's the old implementation:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Reads a file into a byte array
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="filePath">Full path of file to read.</param>
   /// <returns>Byte array with file contents.</returns>
   public static byte[] GetFileBytes(string filePath)
   {
       byte[] fileBytes = null;

       using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       using (var memStr = new MemoryStream())
       {
           byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
           memStr.Position = 0;
           int bytesRead = 0;

           while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
           {
               memStr.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           }

           memStr.Position = 0;
           fileBytes = memStr.GetBuffer();
       }

       return fileBytes;
   }
   ```
3. Here's one of the TweetWithMediaAsync overloads:

   ```
       Status tweet = await twitterCtx.TweetWithMediaAsync(
           status, PossiblySensitive, Latitude, Longitude,
           PlaceID, DisplayCoordinates, imageBytes);
   ```
4. That is now called TweetAsync:

   ```
           var tweet = await twitterCtx.TweetAsync(status);
   ```
5. Here's an example of CreateFavoriteAsync:

   ```
       var status = await twitterCtx.CreateFavoriteAsync(401033367283453953ul);
   ```
6. You have to instantiate TwitterContext - here's an example:

   ```
       var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
   ```

For more information, you can download the source code and see working examples for multiple technologies. The sample project names have the Linq2TwitterDemos_ prefix:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt

Every API call is documented, as well as documentation on other aspects of LINQ to Twitter:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation